# getting error while connection to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a web app using php. I have made a database class which I will access. Now in a new file I'm accessing that class but I am getting error:

```
!) Catchable fatal error: Object of class DbMain could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\baapdevelopers\DBMain.php on line 23
```

Code

```
<?php
class DbMain{
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $dbname = 'test';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';

    public $con;

    function __construct(){
        $this->connect();
    }// this is the main constructor used for initializing the database

    function connect(){
        try{
            $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this-host;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->username, $this->password);
            $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'We\'re sorry but there was an error while trying to connect to the database';
            file_put_contents('connection.errors.txt', $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
}
/* Test.php */

//include_once("DBMain.php");
$db = new DbMain();
?>
```

I dont know why this error is occuring

Comment: you missed arrow " -> " in line 
`$this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->username, $this->password);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
$this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this-host;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->username, $this->password);
```

When you use `$this->dbname` for example in a string, it only sees `$this` as a variable and will thus attempt to transform `$this` (which is really the instance of the class DbMain) to a string. That's what the error message tells you.

Instead, you should escape complex variable names in a string with curly braces (`{$this->dbname}`). Your code then becomes:

```
$this->con = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->dbname}",$this->username, $this->password);
```

More information on this concept can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Comment: And by the way, he forgot the `>` in  `$this-host`

Comment: Yep, also, but I suppose that was a typo.